# Como capturar um campo json em java?

Tags: java, spring

Tenho esse código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String filmes[] = new String[2];

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resposta = restTemplate.getForObject("https:api.....", String.class);

    String resFormatada = resposta.replace("[","");

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resFormatada);
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        filmes[i] = jsonObject.getString("id");
        System.out.println(filmes[i]);
    }
}
```

O retorno da api é:

```
[{"id":"tt3606756","titulo":"Os Incríveis 2","ano":2018,"nota":8.5},{"id":"tt4881806","titulo":"Jurassic World: Reino Ameaçado","ano":2018,"nota":6.7},{"id":"tt5164214","titulo":"Oito Mulheres e um Segredo","ano":2018,"nota":6.3}]
```

Eu gostaria de salvar cada Id em um vetor, porem do jeito que eu faço eu só estou pegando o primeiro e não todos os 3.
Alguem teria como me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está em usar um `JSONObject` logo invés de usar `JSONArray` visto receberes um array e não apenas um objecto. Alterando o código ficas com o seguinte.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resposta = restTemplate.getForObject("https:api.....", String.class);

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resposta);
    String[] filmes = new String[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        filmes[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        System.out.println(filmes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigadoo, deu certo!